# Java generate "stub" for missing dependency/JAR

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Is there a tool that will generate a stub/API Java JAR for missing Gradle/Maven dependencies (for compilation purposes only)?

e.g. I have a Gradle project for which I do not have and cannot get one of the dependencies (a custom JAR). It will therefore not compile. I would like to create a "stub JAR" i.e. API only no implementation, which will allow the code to compile.

Does such a beast exist?

Comment: How is it supposed to know what this API looks like (what interfaces and methods are there) without the JAR file?

Comment: @Thilo I don't know - that would be the cool bit. Maybe it could, naively, compare a list of classes that have been loaded to a list of java "imports" to determine the missing classes. Maybe it would attempt to compile and then deduce what is missing and then generate etc? TBH I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Override the dependency in your build.gradle file with a dependency substitution to return the stub that you have created.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('some.group:some-artifact') with module('substitute.group:subst-artifact:1.0.0')
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, at least not easily.  You could run a build and filter out the errors to make a list of classes and methods that you need to implement.  You could even write code to generate Java source code based on that. But there is no way to automatically know what errors are caused by your missing module and what errors are problems that need to be addressed in another way.